# How to use argument matcher with lazy evaluation in RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

How to evaluate `with` arguments only after `expect` block was evaluated?

```
let(:job) { create(:job) }

it do
      expect { job }
        .to have_enqueued_mail(NotificationMailer, :note)
              .with(
                user: job.user
              )
end
```

In other case job is going to be created outside of the `expect` block, and notification sends `on: create` so expectation is not going to be happen in the `expect` block.

Comment: If you want to check callback: I think you should build the job object outside, then save object inside the expect block. `expect { job.save }.to sth`

Comment: You can set `config.action_mailer.delivery_method` to `:test` and then check `ActionMailer::Base.deliveries` array for the one you are looking for.

Comment: It's not just about the mailer, but also the mock expectation as well.